# Como configurar a propriedade progressBar no toastr plugin?

Tags: javascript, plugin

Estou usando esse [plugin](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr) para mostrar mensagens , mas não estou conseguindo fazer isso.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>toastr examples</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/css/toastr.min.css">

            <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
            </script>
            <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/2.0.2/js/toastr.min.js"></script>
        </head>

        <body class="container">
            <h1>yes</h1>
            <script>

                toastr.info('Are you the 6 fingered man?', "Hey", { timeOut: 4000, progressBar: true });
                console.log(toastr);
            </script>
        </body>

        </html>
```

Eu tentei assim, mas não funcionou:

```
 toastr.info('Are you the 6 fingered man?', "Hey", { timeOut: 4000, progressBar: true });
```

Mas assim apenas para o timeOut funciona perfeitamente.

```
 toastr.info('Are you the 6 fingered man?', "Hey", { timeOut: 4000 });
```

Onde eu posso encontrar um tutorial sobre isso? Onde eu arrei no código acima?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei exatamente o motivo, mas acredito que a referência do CDN está desatualiza, além disso estou usando a versão 3.x e não 2.x do jQuery e funcionou...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Teste o código abaixo para ver funcionando

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title>Page Title</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.css">

</head>
<body>

 <p>YES</p>
 
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.js"></script>

 <script>
 toastr.success('We do have the Kapua suite available.', 'Turtle Bay Resort', {
          "timeOut": 4000, 
          "progressBar": true
        })
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Copiei e colei o seu código e usei a versão 1 e 2 do jquery e também deu certo.

Comment: @PenaPintada então eh problema com o CDN mesmo, o link que pequei foi direto do exemplo deles, e não o que estava na documentação rss. Tem a ordem de indexação tbm... Eu botei os .js no final do documento, não sei se nesse caso tem a ver